# Python BLE discover all UUID characteristics

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

So far, this code is returning me the UUID of the service. But I have several characteristics inside of it, can I discover their UUID?

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def run():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d.metadata)
            
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. It gives you `UUID` but you ask how to get `UUID`? Did you check what is `d.metadata` -  ie. `print(type(d.metadata))` ? maybe it is dictionary and you can get values like from dictionary? OR maybe check what functions/methods it has `print( dir(d.metadat) )` and you will see what you can use. Or maybe you should try directly `d.metadata.UUID` or `d.metadata.uuid`, etc. and maybe you will guess correct function/attribute. OR finally you should find documentation and read it.

Comment: If the documentation had what I asked for , I wouldn't be here. There's the service UUID, and each service has one or more characteristics, each one has its own UUID. Is this last UUID that I'm looking for. But the metadata only have the service UUID

Comment: every day I see many questions from people which didn't  read documentation and didn't even use Google to find solution - and this is why I wrote this comment.

Comment: And thanks for that. I come to stackoverflow as last resource. I tryied to look up a solution in many places, but not many work with BLE, and this is kinda a specific request.
Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: you could add your first comment to question - more people will see it and maybe more people could help. You could add also output from your code and what output you would get.  And second comment can be also useful in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `discover` is only getting the advertising information from the device. At that stage your client will not have resolved the services and know about the characteristics. That information is only available once the client has connected to the device. Browsing the documentation it looks like you get the information you want with `get_services` as that returns the GATT services tree:

https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#bleak.backends.client.BaseBleakClient.get_services